# What is the pattern used in log4j

Tags: java, design-patterns, singleton, log4j, factory-pattern

I needed to understand the design pattern(s) used in log4j library.
Since it provides loggers for various classes, it it a factory ?

Any more inputs/pointers on these is greatly appreciated..

Answer (score 3):

Log4j uses singleton design pattern, as it will have single instance of class.
check this for reference
http://www.oodesign.com/singleton-pattern.html

Answer (score 1):

Which kind of designpattern do you mean? Creational, behavioral or structural?

If you mean creational, I´d agree with the factory-pattern, but when you want to be sure, you could ask Ceki Gülcü (ceki@apache.org, log4j-user@jakarta.apache.org or [through his profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/100970/ceki)), the designer of log4j, who could and would answer this question.

Answer (score 1):

Log4j is Singleton Pattern which comes under Creational design pattern

Answer (score 1):

It is using a mixture of design pattern, is using Singleton and Chain of responsibilities patterns.

I've checked on a e-learning website.